# How to retain advanced SASS nesting option when using correct BEM methodology

Tags: sass, nested, bem

This had been discussed multiple times, but I haven't seen a proper answer yet. I want to use BEM methodology in my code, but I want to **preserve advanced SASS nesting** options for better code readability.

Here's an example of my code:

```
<div class="education">
    <h3 class="education__heading">Heading</h3>
    <div class="education__items">
        <div class="education__item">
            <h4 class="education__faculty">Lorem ipsum</h4>
            <span class="education__subject">Dolor sit amet</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This should be the correct BEM model with 3 level nesting. Here's how the SASS code for this model looks like:

```
.education {

    &__heading {

    }

    &__items {

    }

    &__item {

    }

    &__faculty {

    }

    &__subject {
        
    }
}
```

As far as I know, this is the correct approach, but I miss the option to nest classes in my SASS code (see simplified example below, without the BEM class names):

```
.education {

    .heading {

    }

    .items {

        .item {

            .faculty {

            }

            .subject {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

This structure basically copies the HTML structure and I believe it is very easy to maintain and read. **Is it possible to retain multi-level nesting in SASS when using proper BEM methodology?**

Comment: Are you sure that you want that much specificity for your selectors? It will compile to: `.education .items . item .faculty {}`... If that really is what you want, just create a variable at your parent selector level, and use it instead of the ampersand `&`.

Comment: @AmauryHanser that's a good point, thank you. Although this simplified example wasn't the best one to use I agree the specificity of more than ~3 levels is redundant in most of the cases.

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I know to do this is made of three tricks:

1. Use the `@at-root` rule, it will move a declaration to the top, no matter how deep the nesting goes
2. Save the block selector in a variable, using `&` as the value of the assignation
3. Use `#{}` to insert a variable inside a selector

In your case, it will look like this:

```scss
.education {
    // Save `.education` in the $block variable
    $block: &;

    @at-root #{$block}__heading {
        /* Heading styles */
    }

    @at-root #{$block}__items {
        /* Items styles */

        @at-root #{$block}__item {
            /* Item styles */

            @at-root #{$block}__faculty {
                /* Faculty styles */
            }

            @at-root #{$block}__subject {
                /* Subject styles */
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And will compile to:

```css
.education__heading {
  /* Heading styles */
}
.education__items {
  /* Items styles */
}
.education__item {
  /* Item styles */
}
.education__faculty {
  /* Faculty styles */
}
.education__subject {
  /* Subject styles */
}
```